# Firebase Initialization Crash After Updating com.google.gms:google-services to 4.4.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have recently updated the com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 dependency, and after that, it started crashing my app. The cause was listed as 'Initialize the Firebase.' However, when I downgraded the version of com.google.gms:google-services, it works fine. Please help me with this issue.

Carsh log

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.myproject.activity. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first. at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179) at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(FirebaseMessaging.java:126) at com.myproject.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:478)
```

I am trying to update the dependency, and i have alredy initialized firebase in my project in the Application class like this

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Comment: Can you also update firebase plugin & dependency as well, and check if the issue still exist or not?

Comment: Hello @SohaibAhmed  , thank you for your response. I have already updated all of my dependencies:

"
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.6.0'

"
However, I am still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I was able to resolve the issue by following the suggestion provided by firebase support team. The problem arose after updating the `com.google.gms:google-services` dependency to version 4.4.0, causing my app to crash with the error 'Initialize the Firebase.'

Upon further investigation, I found that updating the Android Gradle Plugin version to 8.1.0, as recommended, fixed the problem. I appreciate the assistance and hope this solution helps others facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try call Init() at `Application.attachContext`, not `Application.onCreate`?

add some log to show the order of calls.

Comment: Hi ,@Fan Applelin
here is the  crash log  and  i have FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); in onCreate of my Application class

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized
in this process com.myproject.activity. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(FirebaseMessaging.java:126)
at com.myproject.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:478)